# where do i find the laravel auth facade class implementation

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, facade

i am trying to find the auth facade class implementation which contains its methods (check(),user() etc.) .
  I have been reffered to the laravel facade class
reference in the laravel docs but none of those classes (authmanager in this case)  seem to have 
the methods used on the facade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitions are given in

```
\Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers
```

and that **trait** is used by

1. Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard
2. Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard
3. Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard

Each of the above classes, individually have a user() function that helps the rest of the GuardHelper functions...

Hope this answers everything

Answer (score 0):

There is a class reference table in the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades#facade-class-reference

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

It will create a helper bootstrap file and your IDE can simply link the class implementation.